# Can I draw with the arrow keys in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I'm looking for a plugin or something that will let me draw by pixel using the arrow keys.  I want to be able to move the "Cursor" to around using the arrow keys instead of the mouse to improve precision.

Comment: I usually zoom in to 500% or bigger, in conjunction with a grid setting of 1x1. Isn't that an option?

Answer (score 1):

Drawing directly is not possible, nor is it possible to create a plug-in that does that on GIMP canvas.
(Although it is possible to have a plug-in that is a whole "sub-aplication" and has its own drawing canvas, like gfig)

One thing that is possible is to move the edges of rectangular or elliptical selections - just create a small selection and before confirming it with `<enter>`, hover the pointer over a handle for that selection. It is them possible to  enlarge or shrink the selection with pixel precision by using the arrow keys.  You can then easily fill the selection by justdragging a color from somewhere into the canvas (`Windows->Docable Dialogs->Colors`  will display a docked color selector which is a nice place from where to drag colors).

If you want to do free-hand drawing, this is of no help at all, but if you just want vertical and horizontal lines with pixel-precision sizes, it might work.

Comment: Actually I cantink of a concept plug-in that would allow it - you'd have to keep the window plug-in open, aside or above GIMP's window and focused  - and it would read the keystrokes, move a selected area, and stamp the paintbrush as desired. It should take 2-4 hours to implement something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux, you can map something like Alt+WIN+Arrow to something like

xdotool mousemove_relative --sync 0 1; xdotool click 1

(this moves down, +1px on the vertical axes, and then simulate a mouse click, so can be mapped to the down arrow)

The way you can map depends on the window manager you are using.

I'm not a windows user, but maybe AutoHotKey can do something similar